# Сервер в samp

Tags: ос, хостинг

У меня такой вопрос: сервер для gta sa сделан на ОС windiws, как его переделать под ОС linux? Просто проблемы начинаются: залил на хост сервер, а он через раз работает из-за того, что мой сервер был создан на ОС windows, а у хоста ОС linux.

Answer (score 1):

Удивительно что вообще работает)) Для линукса есть отдельный сервер Именно под линукс.

```
http://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/Linux_Server_RU
```